# Route not compiled in sub route file

Tags: routes, playframework-2.3

I'm developing an app with Play 2.3.7.
I have this `routes` file :

```
GET          /api-docs                             controllers.ApiHelpController.getResources

GET         /assets/*file                          controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
GET         /swagger-ui/*file                      controllers.Assets.at(path="/public/swagger-ui", file)

->          /v1/episodes                           model_v1_episodes.Routes
->          /v1/seasons                            model_v1_seasons.Routes
->          /v1/series                             model_v1_series.Routes
```

I also have `model_v1_*` files for each model to avoid having too long routes files. Here is one of them

```
GET       /                         controllers.EpisodeController.list()
GET       /:key                     controllers.EpisodeController.load(key: String)
POST      /                         controllers.EpisodeController.create()
DELETE    /:key                     controllers.EpisodeController.delete(key: String)
```

The problem is that when I want to test `EpisodeController.list()` I can't because `EpisodeController` does not exist...

```
@Test
public void list() {
    Result result = callAction(controllers.routes.ref.EpisodeController.list(), new FakeRequest());
    // Assertions on result...
}
```

If I check manually in `target/scala-2.10/src_managed/main/controllers/routes.java`, there is no trace of `EpisodeController` whereas it is present in the `controllers` package. And everything works fine when I `run` my app and test with Swagger.

Comment: Try putting the controllers referred to in the sub-routes in their own distinct package. Otherwise the route compiler will overwrite the generated routes with the main one. https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/1036

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained by @Mikesname in a comment on the question, the problem is that my controllers were in the `controllers` package.
I placed them into `controllers.mypackage` and named my file `mypackage.routes` and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
1 activator clean compile
2 activator eclipse
```

if it doesn't help run tests in debug mode:

- activator -jvm-debug test and check what's the problem...

Maybe logs will tell you something more (both from cmd and from application)

Comment: Nothing anormal shows up with the debug mode. Note that if I copy the routes of `model_v1_episodes.routes` directly inside `routes` and delete `model_v1_episodes.routes` it works fine...